# SQL SERVER 2005 | How do i figure out that there are no writes happening to my data server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

Consider that i have a maintenance activity on my dataserver which hosts a lot of databases. Now before the maintenance , I would like to make sure that there are no writes/updates happening to the database for atleast 2-3 hours. Is there a way to know this ? Although i can make sure that all the jobs contacting the dataserver are all held during the maintenance , Having a way to know this for sure would help.

Thanks

Comment: What is this maintenance that you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sql Server Activity Monitor for Checking the current Activities going on in the server.

In SQL Server Management Studio, You can also open Activity Monitor at any time by pressing CTRL+ALT + A.

In activity monitor you can see.   Active User Tasks,Resource Waits, Data File I/O, etc

You can get a detailed description at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL Server Profiler in order to see if there is any activity on the server.